# SUM difference behind time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with sum differrence behind times.

In database They are duplicate records. For example:

```
_Status________Information__________Time______
Start(1)  |  heating on 20°C        |  10:00
Start(1)  |  heating on 21°C        |  10:20
Stop(0)   |  Heating                |  11:00
Stop(0)   |  Wait for instructions  |  12:00
```

The difference behind record **A(start)** and **C(stop)** is *1 hour*.

When I don't use SUM, I get rows with right time difference.

**Query**

```
SET @end_time=0;

SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(t2.date) - TIME_TO_SEC(t1.date)) AS difference, t1.date AS start, t2.date AS stop, @end_time:=t2.date

    FROM `heating_history` AS t1

    LEFT JOIN `heating_history`  AS t2 ON t2.date > t1.date and t2.status!=1

    WHERE t1.status=1 and TIME_TO_SEC(t1.date) > TIME_TO_SEC(@end_time)
```

**Result**

```
difference  start                   stop                    @end_time:=t2.date
12703   2014-01-29 07:18:32     2014-01-29 10:50:15     2014-01-29 10:50:15
4079    2014-01-29 13:27:12     2014-01-29 14:35:11     2014-01-29 14:35:11
9839    2014-01-29 16:46:12     2014-01-29 19:30:11     2014-01-29 19:30:11
4810    2014-01-29 21:18:11     2014-01-29 22:38:21     2014-01-29 22:38:21
```

---

But when I want SUM of values, I get worng result.

**Query**

```
SET @end_time=0;

SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(t2.date) - TIME_TO_SEC(t1.date)) AS difference, t1.date AS start, t2.date AS stop, @end_time:=t2.date

FROM `heating_history` AS t1

LEFT JOIN `heating_history`  AS t2 ON t2.date > t1.date and t2.status!=1

WHERE t1.status=1 and TIME_TO_SEC(t1.date) > TIME_TO_SEC(@end_time)
```

**Result**

```
difference  start                   stop                    @end_time:=t2.date
258536  2014-01-29 07:18:32     2014-01-29 10:50:15     2014-01-29 10:50:15
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this SQL-Server or MySQL or something else? Also can you add query that returns correct rows and your query that returns incorrect SUM

Comment: I use MySQL. Queries added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is coming from not specifying what you want to `SUM` because there is no group by clause it just SUMs everything that you have. To make sure that you are only Summing the differences that you want use a sub select query in this fashion.

```
SELECT SUM(DIFFERENCE),start,stop
FROM
(
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(t2.date) - TIME_TO_SEC(t1.date)) AS difference, t1.date AS start, t2.date AS stop, @end_time:=t2.date
FROM `heating_history` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `heating_history`  AS t2 ON t2.date > t1.date and t2.status!=1
WHERE t1.status=1 and TIME_TO_SEC(t1.date) > TIME_TO_SEC(@end_time) and DATE(t1.date)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)) as MyQuery
```

You can't just throw `SUM` in the query and expect to get right results. You ether need to specify `GROUP BY` clause or use Sub-Select to `SUM` your correct results.